# Targetting overseas users to .co.uk site

Tags: seo

I have a well established .co.uk site. The site is mainly specific to the UK but parts of it are starting to get traffic from other countries. I'd like to get better search rankings from overseas but maintain my British user base. I own the same domain `.net`.

Would I be better:

a) moving to the `.net` domain,
 b) splitting the site into two,
 c) have one site but put different pages in different domains,
 d) staying as is?

Answer (score 1):

All your options are viable, they just become requirements in order to fulfil a determined organisation structure, business processes and target audience. You just need to be congruent with all the things you do offline and online.

The TLD you choose will help you define your online business purpose to search engines and most importantly to users. So you need to consider how having a .net site will assist you defining you online purpose. For this reason I hope that your potentially .net site is not going to be used for ecommerce purposes.

The decision to serve or not an overseas audience with a brand new website will depends on how you are currently satisfying people’s search intent, whenever these are UK users outside UK, why users will prefer your UK site rather than a local website, how your website is technically setup and developed, etc.

Another important question more related to your business would be, how are you planning to serve internationally, how your operations will be impacted if your international audience increases, would having a separate website help with the operations, customer service, delivery or response times? How are you going to compete with local business? All this will be increasingly noticeable and Google will take note of that and reward you or not with better rankings.

a), b) and c) options are SEO technically feasible, but if you are not able to compete at the same level is not worthy having a separate website. Many webmasters have experienced good results having one domain and splitting the site into two (option b).  Option c is the less favorable because you are basically starting two new websites and even though they have a good parent or referrer, everything else staying the same, it will take some time for them to take off. Using option a is a good alternative assuming the audience is on the rise and your are able to send authority signals to search engines. Here implementing hreflang meta tag is of a vital importance.

Comment: The UK site is aimed at UK viewers and the content is entirely UK-specific. It also appeals to exiles, or people interested in the UK. However, some of the newer content really belongs to a different site I feel because it is not really related to the original domain name. I have crammed it all into one site partly because it is established and partly because it was easier to do. I feel there are essentially two distinct audiences. If I move it to a new site I'll have to 301 the old pages to the new ones and take the hit from Google if the traffic drops until the site establishes a reputation.

Comment: @RobSedgwick not sure how 301s to an external source would impact your website in terms of SEO. I recommend reviewing the specs, to me 301s are for internal control and if you do it, make sure it will be a temporal solution while pages get deindex, as long as your pages hasn’t generated backlinks. What I would recommend if you are going to move onto another domain is that you create a silo about that content and about that audience, move on and create new content for new domain and start creating links, citations, page author, and everything onsite possible to point to the new domain.

Comment: @RobSedgwick It is not recommended to have internal links generating 301s, generating 301s to external sources is even worse. is not a good UX. Create a new entity, including an author and so everybody understand that this new entity and author is a big contributor to your UK site.